# Native way to insert a dict into SQLite with row factory, if possible with auto-growing number of columns

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

As detailed in [How can I get dict from sqlite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300464/how-can-i-get-dict-from-sqlite-query),  `row_factory` is helpful to get a `dict` when querying a SQLite database:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
conn.execute('create table test (a text, b text, c int)')
conn.execute('insert into test values (?, ?, ?)', ('hello', 2, 17))
for r in conn.execute('select * from test'):
    print(dict(r))
# {'a': 'hello', 'b': '2', 'c': 17}
```

The result of the query is *directly* a `dict`, which is sometimes very useful.

**Question: is it also possible, when using `row_factory` to easily `INSERT` directly a `dict` into the database?**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814250/insert-a-python-dict-into-an-sqlite-db/8814345#8814345) is a partial solution:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
conn.execute('insert into test ({}) values ({})'.format(','.join(d.keys()), ','.join(['?'] * len(d))), tuple(d.values()))
```

but it's not really "pythonic".

**Is there a cleaner way to insert a dict directly into a SQLite DB, for example, by using `row_factory`?**

Side-remark: it would be great that it would also "auto-grow" the table definition, i.e. if I insert `d = {'newkey': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`, it would automatically add a new column to the table.

Comment: You can name the arguments: conn.execute('insert into test values (:a, :b, :c)', d)

Comment: @jerry We need a solution without hardcoding the column names in the query, the query should be automatically generated.

Comment: I think that you could do similar things with sqlalchemy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664700/how-to-add-all-elements-from-python-dictionary-to-database, although I would prefer using string manipulation.

Comment: It looks like `row_factory` exists just to interpret the results received from the database, so it isn't really any more native than if you just ran the return value of `conn.execute` through another function, and it can only be used when "reading" from the database, so it won't be of much help with an `insert` statement.

Comment: And as for "natively" inserting a dictionary into the database, I'm afraid that isn't possible without peeling off a few abstraction layers. SQLite is meant to be interacted using SQL, which to my knowledge doesn't have the same notion of hashmaps that python does.

Answer (score 4):

For the reasons I mentioned in the comments, it probably isn't possible to do this "natively" without replacing the SQL interface with your own way of writing to the DB file, but it certainly is possible to make this code more "pythonic" as you mention:

```py
def sqlify_list(string_iterable):
    """ ('a', 'b', 'c') -> '(a, b, c)' """
    return f'({",".join(string_iterable)})'

def insert_dict_into_table(conn, table_name, _dict):
    conn.execute(
        'insert into {table_name} {keys} values {replacement_fields}'.format(
            table_name=table_name,
            keys=sqlify_list(d), # dict.__iter__ yields the keys, so .keys() isn't necessary
            replacement_fields=sqlify_list('?'*len(d)) # str.__iter__ yields characters, so ','.join('?'*5) is equivalent to ','.join(['?']*5)
        ),
        d.values()
    )

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
insert_dict_into_table(conn, 'test', d)
```

As for

> it would be great that it would also "auto-grow" the table definition

To my knowledge, relational databases aren't typically used for this sort of ad-hoc schema changing. Perhaps it would be simpler to store the dictionary in the database as JSON? Or perhaps switch to a schema-less DB like MongoDB?